# Add TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 cipher suite to a C# application running in Windows 7

Tags: c#

I've created a C# application for my personal use to download a program that changes daily from a website.  The application runs in Windows 7.  Recently I've started getting an error "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."  After looking into the error, it turns out the server changed the cipher suits it can support and it appears the server switched to a cipher suit that is not included in Windows 7.

Using Wireshark I found out that Firefox uses the TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 cipher suit to communicate with that website.  This cipher suite is not part of Windows 7.

Is there a way to make a C# application use a custom/external cipher suit (one that does not come with Windows)?